# Invalid interaction application command(discord.js slash commands using WOKCommands)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js and WOKCommands to use slash commands, but when entered in Discord it gives me an error "Invalid interaction application command"

Here is the code for the command:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

// Simple command for the message
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    slash: "both",
    testOnly: false,
    description: "Command to figure out what your current ping is. Also shows API Latency",
    // Executing the message command
    execute(client, message, cmd, args, Discord) {
        // Creating the Embed const
        const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            // ALL EMBED VALUES
            .setColor("#ffdbac")
            .setTitle("Ping")
            .setDescription("Pong! Latency is **" + (Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp) + "ms**. API Latency is **" + message.client.ws.ping + "ms**")
            .setThumbnail(`https://cometiclachlan.github.io/Uploads/pingpong-removebg.png`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter("v1.2", `https://cometiclachlan.github.io/Uploads/Checkpoint-removebg.png`);

        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    },
};
```

That is the code for the command only if I need to show the code for the main script as well. I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

You Can not use Message in Slash Commands You'l Need to change it to

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

// Simple command for the message
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    slash: "both",
    testOnly: false,
    description: "Command to figure out what your current ping is. Also shows API Latency",
    // Executing the message command
    callback : ({client, message, cmd, args, Discord}) => {
        if (message) {
        // Creating the Embed const
        const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        // ALL EMBED VALUES
        .setColor("#ffdbac")
        .setTitle("Ping")
        .setDescription("Pong! Latency is **" + (Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp) + "ms**. API Latency is **" + client.ws.ping + "ms**")
        .setThumbnail(`https://cometiclachlan.github.io/Uploads/pingpong-removebg.png`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter("v1.2", `https://cometiclachlan.github.io/Uploads/Checkpoint-removebg.png`);

        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
        }
        // Slash Command
        const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        ...
        return newEmbed
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, code-only or command-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to people with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)