# Why do I get the error 'Invalid interaction application command' when I use this Slash command in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I try do use this slash command it says 'Invalid interaction application command'. How do I fix this? I can show more code if needed.

```
const Command = require('../structures/command.js');
const config = require('../data/config.json');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "ping",
    description: "Shows the ping of the bot.",
    type: "BOTH",
    slashCommandOptions: [],
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        if (message.author.id === config.dev) {
            // const pingEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            //     .setTitle(`Bot Ping: ${client.ws.ping} ms`)
            //     .setAuthor('System')
            //     // .setFooter(`${client.ws.ping} ms`)
            //     .setColor('5FA6E0')

            const m = await message.reply(`Bot Ping: ${client.ws.ping} ms`);
            const msg = message instanceof Discord.CommandInteraction ? await message.fetchReply() : m;
            msg.edit(`Ping: ${client.ws.ping} ms\nMessage Ping: ${msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp} ms`);
        } else {
            message.reply(`Must be a developer to use the command [${this.name}]`);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I think this should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188270/invalid-interaction-application-commanddiscord-js-slash-commands-using-wokcomma